# Not able to parse Devnagari unicode character

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to match consonant characters to match some test cases for cardinal number of Devanagari (Hindi) for the [Recognizer text project](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/01/24/contributing-luis-microsoft-recognizers-text-part-1/). But they are failing always. Could anyone point me to some docs for unicode char or point what i'm missing here.

JFI: As example for 3(in hindi it is called as तीन) I have tried using Hindi word as well as Unicode character equal to Hindi word but its not working.

Below is the code from yaml file:

```
ZeroToNineIntegerRegex: !simpleRegex

def: (सात|आठ|चार|पाँच|शून्य|नौ|एक|दो|छह|(\u0924\u0940\u0928))

TwoToNineIntegerRegex: !simpleRegex

def: (तीन|सात|आठ|चार|पाँच|नौ|दो|छह)

CardinalNumberMap: !dictionary
types: [ string, long ]
entries:
शून्य: 0
एक: 1
दो: 2
तीन: 3
```

This is the json test case:

```
{
"Input": "तीन",
"NotSupportedByDesign": "javascript,python,java",
"Results": [
{
 "Text": "तीन",
 "TypeName": "Number",
 "Resolution": {
 "subtype": "integer",
 "value": "3"
},
 "Start": 0,
 "End": 4
 }]
}
```

The fail message :

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected<1>. Actual <0>

Thanks you Advance.

Comment: how is this c# and which piece of code contains that failing assert?

Comment: (in other words: please provide a [minimal, complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example).

Comment: Hi @dlatikay, The [Recognizer Text](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/.NET) project is build in c# .net that's why I have used the c# tag. And, That's main reason to ask to community if they can (preferrably Hindi origin buddies) tell about my regex. Hope this will clear your doubts.

Comment: I doubt that the regex is the problem. It looks fine. writing तीन or spelling out T-Ii-N in unicode code points would not make a difference. using `RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` is correct too. I'd focus on finding the failing `Assert` in code, there are plenty, can you debug the `Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.Number` part, the assert would act like a breakpoint when debugging?